# How to get custom image field of specific post id

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, id, advanced-custom-fields, images

I have a page where I'm pulling in content from another post, outside of the loop.

I've been successfull at getting the content of the specified post, but I cannot get the image from a custom field (advanced custom image field).

This is working to get the content from the post who's ID is 299:

```
$my_id = 299;
$post_id_299 = get_post($my_id);

$content_299 = $post_id_299->post_content;
$content_299 = apply_filters('the_content', $content_299);
$content_299 = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content_299);
$content_299_chars = 238; 
$modcontent_299 = substr($content_299, 0, $content_299_chars);
```

`<p><?php echo $modcontent_299; ?></p>`

This is what I'm after to get the image from the post who's ID is 299 (if it exists):

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image', 299);
$size = 'full';
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size ); 

if( get_field('image') ):
   echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="' . the_title() .'" width="238" height="158" />';
endif;
```

I'm sure I need to change some of these variables to get the image field from the specific post id, similar to how it's done to get the content, but I'm confused at this point as to how to do that for a custom field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see documentation for [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/). change:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image');
```

to pass the post ID as second argument:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image', 299);
```

or:

```
$attachment_id = get_field('image', $my_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Milo, unfortunately that doesn't work - nothing returns.

Comment: is your field set to return the image ID, and not an image object or array of some kind?

Comment: I see - the remaining problem was in the conditional, I needed to also update `if( get_field('image') ):` with `if( get_field('image', 299) ):` - that was it!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i think your using your code to show title and alt on post image then try it.

```
    $post_title  = get_the_title($my_id);

    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($my_id,
        'full', 
        array(
            'alt'   => $post_title, 
            'title' => $post_title,
            'class' => 'my_post_img_class'
        )
    );
```

it will echo

```
<img src="your_image_path.jpg" alt="post_title" title="post_title" class="my_post_img_class" />
```

or use this below function to get custom post field `get_post_field('post_content', $my_id);`